# How to set data labels for XY Plot using python pptx

Tags: python, python-docx, python-pptx

I'm trying to set the labels for the points in a XY Chart (Scatter Plot) using python-pptx. My code is as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'x' : np.random.random(20)*100,
            'y' : np.random.random(20)
})

x = df.x.to_list()
y = df.y.to_list()


def update_xychart(chart, df):
    chart_data = XyChartData()
    plot = chart.plots[0]
    series_1 = chart_data.add_series('Model 1')
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        series_1.add_data_point(x[i],y[i])
    chart.replace_data(chart_data)
    for index in range(0, 20):
        plot.XyPoints[index].data_label.text_frame.text = 'Label' + str(index)
```

I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'XyPlot' object has no attribute 'XyPoints'`. I also tried `plot.points[index].data_label.text_frame.text = 'Label' + str(index)` but didn't work. What is the correct way to access and set the labels for the xy (scatter) chart? Also, can I set the color of every individual marker i.e. the dot/triangle/cross used to represent x-y value on the scatter plot?

Comment: @WilliamMartens thanks for this, but this isn't related as this is using `matplotlib` and I'm looking for a solution with `python-pptx`

Comment: Try doing this series by series, like `plot.series[0].points`. You can only use properties and methods that are implemented, and guessing what those are is pretty error-prone (although I do that myself sometimes). Best to refer to the API documentation to work out how to get to where the right properties are: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#xyseries-objects

Comment: @scanny thank you, that's what I was trying to do. I think that `plot.series[0].points.data_label` should work but that doesn't seem to. What would be the right way to access the data_label?

Comment: @scanny I was able to access the data label for each point using the code `for index in range(0,len(x)):
        series_1.add_data_point(x[index],y[index])
        current_point = plot.series[0].points[index]
        current_point.data_label = 'Label' + str(index)` but then I get an error `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. Is the functionality to set the attribute not built yet or my understanding isn't right (and I'm highly positive this might be the case)

Comment: @Rajat  Okay, thanks for telling me that!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, in your code you are missing the points object. Here it is with my example.

```
for shapes in slide:
  if shapes.has_chart:
      if shapes.chart.chart_title.text_frame.text=='Chart':
        for index in range (0,8):      
shapes.chart.plots[0].series[0].points[index].data_label.text_frame.text='Label' + str(index)
```